# Write Data as Json from DataFrame to Azure Blob Storage

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, spark-shell

I have some data in dataframe which i have to convert to json and store it into Azure Blob Storage.
Is there any way to achieve this?
Below are the steps which i have tried. I am trying it from spark-shell.

```
val df = spark.sql("select * from historic_data.all_historic_data").show()

spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.key.<STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME>.blob.core.windows.net","STORAGE_ACCOUNT_KEY")

df.write.mode(SaveMode.Append).json("wasbs://BlobStorageContainer@<STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME>.blob.core.windows.net/<FOLDER_PATH_OF BLOB>/")
```

While running the write command i am getting below error

```
org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.AzureException: com.microsoft.azure.storage.StorageException: The specifed resource name contains invalid characters.
  at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.AzureNativeFileSystemStore.retrieveMetadata(AzureNativeFileSystemStore.java:2208)
  at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.NativeAzureFileSystem.getFileStatusInternal(NativeAzureFileSystem.java:2673)
  at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.NativeAzureFileSystem.getFileStatus(NativeAzureFileSystem.java:2618)
  at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.exists(FileSystem.java:1448)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:92
```

Is there anything i have missed while providing blob details?
below is screen shot of my storage account :

[image]

I havent seen any similiar kind of question here which will WRITE from dataframe as Json into Azure Blob.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The specifed resource name contains invalid characters.**

Message is clear about the problem. You are using uppercase characters in the container name, which is [not allowed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/naming-and-referencing-containers--blobs--and-metadata#container-names), so change BlobStorageContainer to blobstoragecontainer.

A full list of rules can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/naming-and-referencing-containers--blobs--and-metadata).

Comment: Thank you..it worked..
correct as ```df.write.mode(SaveMode.Append).json("wasbs://<container_name@<storage_account_name>.blob.core.windows.net/<folder_path_of blob>/") ```and worked fine.